# Eclipse find won't do a non-greedy match

Tags: regex, eclipse

I have the following line of code in a Java file in Eclipse:

```
private Map<Integer, ComponentManager> compManagerMap;
```

When I hit CTRL+F and try to find `omp.*?Map` (with the Regular expressions box checked), Eclipse highlights `omponentManager> compManagerMap` instead of `ompManagerMap`.

I read that using a ? in the regular expression will result in a non-greedy match, but Eclipse is still doing a greedy match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does its job correctly. See the demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/12). Note that matching starts from left and progresses towards the right.

So matching starts with the first `omp` upto next `Map` string, it does its job perfectly. If there were two `Map` strings, then it would return two matches. See the demo of non-greedy match [here](http://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/13)

If you want the second `omp` string to be matched then try the below regex,

```
omp(?:(?!omp).)*?Map
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/14)

It would match the substring `ompManagerMap` because it doesn't contain the string `omp`.

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `omp` Matches the literal `omp` string.
- `(?:(?!omp).)*?` Matches any charcter not of the string `omp` zero or more times. `?` after `*` does a shortest match.
- `Map` Matches the literal `Map` string.

Comment: That regex you gave me also matches *ompIgnoredMsgCountMap*.  Can you suggest a new regex that doesn't match *ompIgnoredMsgCountMap*?

Comment: @pacoverflow post the full input.